# how can get uri of an specific android application programatically?

Tags: java, android

i want get URI of an android application pro grammatically in another app
i want install an apk in my project programatically but i cannot check that if it is install or not i want if it is exists in my device only call it so i need URI of this app but i dont have any uri of it
how can get uri of an apk programatically
uri should be pakage name of application 
how can get this uri programatically in android?

```
  Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(apkURI);
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

**how can get URIof an specific APK?**

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try it will list out package list of app in your device

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
 PackageManager pm;
 pm = getPackageManager();
 //  get a list of installed apps.
 packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
  ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
 //packageInfo.packageName contains package name
  }
```